# How to separate a text with delimiter into several columns called E1 to Ei in SQL?

Tags: sql, loops

I have a column in my table which includes one to several entity numbers in each row and each separated by ';' like below:

```
Entity ID

E123;E435;E65798
-----------------
E7865
-----------------
E6788;E47986
-------------
.

.
.
```

I would like to have these entity numbers in separate columns but in some cells there is only one entity id and in some of them even like 20 entity ids. how can I make a loop to separate them and name each column like E1,E2,....En.

Thanks,
Aram

Comment: what rdbms? why loops?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Storing multiple delimited values in a single column is a **very** bad idea. You should fix your data model

Comment: That's the data extracted from other team in my company and I have to deal with it. I want to do the inner join another table on this Entity ID column but with this format I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can any one maybe help me on put these entity id's on different rows? I think now maybe this would be another way.

Comment: We are still waiting for you to tell us what database you are working with.